# issue with adding a map to a list using each closure

Tags: groovy

I am trying to add a map to a list using the each closure. The sample is like this

```
def list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
def titles = []
def map = [:]
list.each{
   map.put('index', xxxx)
   map.put('title', xxxxx)
   titles.add(map)
}
```

If I print the value of the final tiles list I notice that the map items repeat only the values from the first item in list. It looks like the map is getting overwritten with only the value of the first item in the original list.

Why does this happen and what is the way to get the correct value for the map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're adding the same map instance every time then changing all those instances each loop

Move `def map = [:]` inside the each closure

Answer (score 1):

As the other poster commented, you need to instantiate a new map inside the each closure. But, you can do this much more 'Groovier' like this:

```
def list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
def titles = []

list.each{ value -> titles << ['index':'xxx', 'title':'xxxx'] }
```

In your example you are not even using the value from the list as you iterate. If you are just trying to force it to process a specific number of iterations, you could change it to:

```
def titles = []
list.each{ value -> titles << ['index':'xxx', 'title':'xxxx'] }
```

Or more simply, use a range:

```
(1..4)*.collect{ idx -> ['index':idx, 'title':"$idx:xxxx"] }.flatten()
```

Which produces a List of Map:

```
[[index:1, title:1:xxxx], [index:2, title:2:xxxx], [index:3, title:3:xxxx], [index:4, title:4:xxxx]]
```